# Access a nested dict with unknown keys in the path in asnible

Tags: ansible

I am having a problem that I could not find a solution for yet.
I collecting some inventory data from devices and get the data like this:

```
{
    "inventory_items": {
        "main": {
            "chassis": {
                "ASR1001-X": {
                    "descr": "Cisco ASR1001-X Chassis",
                    "name": "Chassis",
                    "pid": "ASR1001-X",
                    "sn": "123456789",
                    "vid": "V02  "
                }
            },
            "non-chassis": {
                "ASR1001-X": {
                    "descr": "Cisco ASR1001-X Route Processor",
                    "name": "module R0",
                    "pid": "ASR1001-X",
                    "sn": "123456789",
                    "vid": "V02  "
                },
                "GLC-SX-MMD": {
                    "descr": "GE SX",
                    "name": "subslot 0/0 transceiver 3",
                    "pid": "GLC-SX-MMD",
                    "sn": "123456789",
                    "vid": "V01  "
                },
                "SFP-10G-LR": {
                    "descr": "SFP+ 10GBASE-LR",
                    "name": "subslot 0/0 transceiver 1",
                    "pid": "SFP-10G-LR",
                    "sn": "123456789",
                    "vid": "V02  "
                },
                "SP7041-E-R": {
                    "descr": "GE T",
                    "name": "subslot 0/0 transceiver 7",
                    "pid": "SP7041-E-R",
                    "sn": "123456789",
                    "vid": "V02  "
                },
                "SPA-1X10GE-WL-V2": {
                    "descr": "1-port 10 Gigabit Ethernet Shared Port Adapter XFP based",
                    "name": "SPA subslot 0/1",
                    "pid": "SPA-1X10GE-WL-V2",
                    "sn": "123456789",
                    "vid": "V02  "
                },
                "XFP-10G-MM-SR": {
                    "descr": "10GBASE-SR/SW",
                    "name": "subslot 0/1 transceiver 0",
                    "pid": "XFP-10G-MM-SR",
                    "sn": "123456789",
                    "vid": "V03  "
                }
            }
        },
        "slot": {
            "Power Supply Module 0": {
                "other": {
                    "Power Supply Module 0": {
                        "descr": "Cisco ASR1001-X AC Power Supply",
                        "name": "Power Supply Module 0",
                        "pid": "ASR1001-X-PWR-AC",
                        "sn": "123456789",
                        "vid": "V01  "
                    }
                }
            },
            "Power Supply Module 1": {
                "other": {
                    "Power Supply Module 1": {
                        "descr": "Cisco ASR1001-X AC Power Supply",
                        "name": "Power Supply Module 1",
                        "pid": "ASR1001-X-PWR-AC",
                        "sn": "123456789",
                        "vid": "V01  "
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to loop thru the items, but I am not really interested in the path and cannot predict it. Problem is that ihn the given example to access the first item would be

```
inventory_items['main']['chassis']
```

but for the 2nd item it is

```
inventory_items['main']['non-chassis']
```

and for the other items it is

```
inventory_items['slot']
```

I don't know how to loop thru the items if the path is different for each item. I am only interested the dict per item, not the path. But I have no idea how to access them.
Is there a way to just lookup the keys/value for per item, but keep them as one dict per item?

What I would like to get to is a list that in can loop thru with "with_items" like this

```
{
    "inventory_items": {
                "ASR1001-X": {
                    "descr": "Cisco ASR1001-X Chassis",
                    "name": "Chassis",
                    "pid": "ASR1001-X",
                    "sn": "123456789",
                    "vid": "V02  "
                },
                "ASR1001-X": {
                    "descr": "Cisco ASR1001-X Route Processor",
                    "name": "module R0",
                    "pid": "ASR1001-X",
                    "sn": "123456789",
                    "vid": "V02  "
                },
                "GLC-SX-MMD": {
                    "descr": "GE SX",
                    "name": "subslot 0/0 transceiver 3",
                    "pid": "GLC-SX-MMD",
                    "sn": "123456789",
                    "vid": "V01  "
                },
                "GLC-TE": {
                    "descr": "GE T",
                    "name": "subslot 0/0 transceiver 7",
                    "pid": "GLC-TE",
                    "sn": "123456789",
                    "vid": "V01  "
                },
                "Power Supply Module 0": {
                        "descr": "Cisco ASR1001-X AC Power Supply",
                        "name": "Power Supply Module 0",
                        "pid": "ASR1001-X-PWR-AC",
                        "sn": "123456789",
                        "vid": "V01  "
                 },
                 "Power Supply Module 1": {
                        "descr": "Cisco ASR1001-X AC Power Supply",
                        "name": "Power Supply Module 1",
                        "pid": "ASR1001-X-PWR-AC",
                        "sn": "123456789",
                        "vid": "V01  "
                 }
      }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do with your list, you speak about you dont know to do, what result do you want? show the result you want could help

Comment: I have made an update with my expected result. I hope this explains it better.

Comment: ok the last dict has always the same keys, descr, name, pid ....?

Comment: yes, the schema for the last dict is always the same.

Comment: you cant have this result, because you cant have same key in dict: ASR1001-X, or you have to have a list in final result...  see my answer i take a list in final result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keys are not unique create a list. For example, there are two keys with the same name `ASR1001-X`

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        iitems: "{{ iitems|d([]) + _keys|zip(_vals)|map('combine') }}"
      loop: "{{ inventory_items.main.keys()|list }}"
      vars:
        _list: "{{ inventory_items.main[item]|dict2items }}"
        _keys: "{{ _list|map(attribute='key')|
                         map('community.general.dict_kv', 'key') }}"
        _vals: "{{ _list|map(attribute='value') }}"
    - set_fact:
        iitems: "{{ iitems|d([]) + _keys|zip(_vals)|map('combine') }}"
      loop: "{{ inventory_items.slot.keys()|list }}"
      vars:
        _list: "{{ inventory_items.slot[item].other|dict2items }}"
        _keys: "{{ _list|map(attribute='key')|
                         map('community.general.dict_kv', 'key') }}"
        _vals: "{{ _list|map(attribute='value') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  iitems|sort(attribute='key'):
  - descr: Cisco ASR1001-X Chassis
    key: ASR1001-X
    name: Chassis
    pid: ASR1001-X
    sn: '123456789'
    vid: 'V02  '
  - descr: Cisco ASR1001-X Route Processor
    key: ASR1001-X
    name: module R0
    pid: ASR1001-X
    sn: '123456789'
    vid: 'V02  '
  - descr: GE SX
    key: GLC-SX-MMD
    name: subslot 0/0 transceiver 3
    pid: GLC-SX-MMD
    sn: '123456789'
    vid: 'V01  '
  - descr: Cisco ASR1001-X AC Power Supply
    key: Power Supply Module 0
    name: Power Supply Module 0
    pid: ASR1001-X-PWR-AC
    sn: '123456789'
    vid: 'V01  '
  - descr: Cisco ASR1001-X AC Power Supply
    key: Power Supply Module 1
    name: Power Supply Module 1
    pid: ASR1001-X-PWR-AC
    sn: '123456789'
    vid: 'V01  '
  - descr: SFP+ 10GBASE-LR
    key: SFP-10G-LR
    name: subslot 0/0 transceiver 1
    pid: SFP-10G-LR
    sn: '123456789'
    vid: 'V02  '
  - descr: GE T
    key: SP7041-E-R
    name: subslot 0/0 transceiver 7
    pid: SP7041-E-R
    sn: '123456789'
    vid: 'V02  '
  - descr: 1-port 10 Gigabit Ethernet Shared Port Adapter XFP based
    key: SPA-1X10GE-WL-V2
    name: SPA subslot 0/1
    pid: SPA-1X10GE-WL-V2
    sn: '123456789'
    vid: 'V02  '
  - descr: 10GBASE-SR/SW
    key: XFP-10G-MM-SR
    name: subslot 0/1 transceiver 0
    pid: XFP-10G-MM-SR
    sn: '123456789'
    vid: 'V03  '
```

---

It is also possible to create a dictionary, but the identical keys will override each other. For example, note that only one `ASR1001-X` is included in the resulting dictionary below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        iitems: "{{ iitems|d({})|combine(inventory_items.main[item]) }}"
      loop: "{{ inventory_items.main.keys()|list }}"
    - set_fact:
        iitems: "{{ iitems|d({})|combine(inventory_items.slot[item].other) }}"
      loop: "{{ inventory_items.slot.keys()|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  iitems:
    ASR1001-X:
      descr: Cisco ASR1001-X Route Processor
      name: module R0
      pid: ASR1001-X
      sn: '123456789'
      vid: 'V02  '
    GLC-SX-MMD:
      descr: GE SX
      name: subslot 0/0 transceiver 3
      pid: GLC-SX-MMD
      sn: '123456789'
      vid: 'V01  '
    Power Supply Module 0:
      descr: Cisco ASR1001-X AC Power Supply
      name: Power Supply Module 0
      pid: ASR1001-X-PWR-AC
      sn: '123456789'
      vid: 'V01  '
    Power Supply Module 1:
      descr: Cisco ASR1001-X AC Power Supply
      name: Power Supply Module 1
      pid: ASR1001-X-PWR-AC
      sn: '123456789'
      vid: 'V01  '
    SFP-10G-LR:
      descr: SFP+ 10GBASE-LR
      name: subslot 0/0 transceiver 1
      pid: SFP-10G-LR
      sn: '123456789'
      vid: 'V02  '
    SP7041-E-R:
      descr: GE T
      name: subslot 0/0 transceiver 7
      pid: SP7041-E-R
      sn: '123456789'
      vid: 'V02  '
    SPA-1X10GE-WL-V2:
      descr: 1-port 10 Gigabit Ethernet Shared Port Adapter XFP based
      name: SPA subslot 0/1
      pid: SPA-1X10GE-WL-V2
      sn: '123456789'
      vid: 'V02  '
    XFP-10G-MM-SR:
      descr: 10GBASE-SR/SW
      name: subslot 0/1 transceiver 0
      pid: XFP-10G-MM-SR
      sn: '123456789'
      vid: 'V03  '
```

---

**Notes**

- See the filter [*community.general.dict_kv*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide.html#dictionaries)
- The collection [Community.General](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/index.html#community-general) must be installed to use the filter above

Answer (score 0):

so `you dont know exactly the structure of dictionary`, to use a general program, i suggest you to use a custom filter.

Create a folder **filter_plugins** in your playbook folder and create a file **myfilter.py** with a filter named **customfilter**.

myfilter.py: it searches the first key which is not a dict, and i traps its parent key

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class FilterModule(object):
    parent = ""
    result=[]
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'customfilter': self.customfilter
        }
    
    def loopping(self, obj):
        for k in obj:            
            if type(obj[k]) is dict:
                self.parent= k
                self.loopping(obj[k])
            else:
                self.result.append({self.parent: obj})
                break
        return
 
    def customfilter(self, obj):
        for k in obj:
            self.loopping(obj[k])  
        return self.result
```

the playbook to use it:

```
- name: "make this working"
  hosts: localhost

  vars:
    inventory_items:
      main:
        chassis:
          ASR1001-X:
            descr: Cisco ASR1001-X Chassis
            name: Chassis
            pid: ASR1001-X
            sn: '123456789'
            vid: 'V02  '
           :
           :
        Power Supply Module 1:
          other:
            Power Supply Module 1:
              descr: Cisco ASR1001-X AC Power Supply
              name: Power Supply Module 1
              pid: ASR1001-X-PWR-AC
              sn: '123456789'
              vid: 'V01  '


  tasks:
    - name: Debug
      set_fact:
        inventory_items: "{{ inventory_items | customfilter }}"
    
    - name: display
      debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_items }}"
```

the result is the same you want except is in list format